# Can we find out the software components which are currently resident in the memory.

Tags: performance, ram, memory-usage

Can we find out the software components which are currently resident in the memory. If yes, how?
Any command to find the software components?

Comment: what do you mean by software components?

Comment: applications which are currently resident in memory.

Comment: According to me memory resident programs are those ,which remains in the memory and OS is not permitted to swap these to storage device. AM I right?

Comment: you mean memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to assume that your application is either completely in memory or not. But this is not the case. There are different types of data loaded for an application and all are handled slightly differently:

1. the binary of the application
2. shared libraries needed by the application
3. space allocated by your application for data
4. memory mapped files allocated by your application

Nevertheless, at any point in time it is mostly at the descretion of the Linux kernel to decide what is actually in memory and what not. Loading data into memory is typically done in pages of 4096 bytes, so even each of 1 to 4 above may be in memory only partly.

The total size of what is in memory for your process is called [resident set size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_set_size), typically called RSS. When you run `htop` or `top` or `ps` it is the column `RES` or `RSS` that contains the information you want.

I must admit, however, that I am not sure if shared libraries are counted into it or whether they are separated out in the `SHR` (for shared) column.